# How do I check if an id in a query string is valid?

Tags: php

I am passing a database generated id value in a link to another page. In the receiving page where I call `$_GET`, I want to protect against people inserting bogus values after the `?` in the url (e.g. www.mysite.com?id=43).

I want to check the incoming value and make sure it's a valid id from the database, or is there a way to just check the value for NULL or empty? This is what I've tried:

Source page:

```
 echo "<a href=\"get-post-pg2.php?id=" .urlencode($row['id']) ."\">Second Page</a>";
```

Target page:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($_GET)) {
    echo $id;
} else
    echo 'foo';
}
```

Comment: isset() is a good way of checking the value!

Comment: To make sure to have only integer value you can use `echo (int)$id;`

Comment: `empty()` checks isset, null, and the empty string.  But if the value must be protected, you really should use `$_SESSION` to persist rather than `$_GET` to pass it to another page on your own site.

Comment: Side note: `isset($_GET)` is *always* true, same for all the other superglobals. "Set" is not the same as "has no value(s)".

Comment: Like Michael said, you should not use $_GET in this case for security purpose. One of the main rule is : "Never trust user input".

Comment: @madmartigan obviously only if part of the url e.g variable=...

Comment: @yehuda: Not 100% sure what you're saying. I'm talking about the `$_GET` variable itself, not any particular index, like in OP's code: `if(isset($_GET))` <-- always true

Comment: @madmartigan oh sorry, thought you meant with the variable specified inside the $_GET[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is cast the $_GET variable to an integer...

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

Then check if empty..

```
if(!empty($id)){
     // process code
}
```

Any string will be converted to zero which returns as empty in php.
Then check to see if that id exists in your database!

Comment: Sweet! This works perfectly! The data isn't crucial, I just want to learn better coding practices. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: `(int) $_GET['id']` will return `1` for `1 Oops!`, so maybe casting to int isn't necessarily the most appropriate solution (canonical urls?). Why not just query the database for `$_GET['id']` without checking it? If the row doesn't exist, you show a 404, doesn't matter what the user passes in. As Col. Shrapnel mentions, you can't prevent the user from typing into the address bar whatever they want.

Comment: In my query function, I already test the query and if it fails, I redirect to an oops page. So this step isn't necessary?

Comment: @Stubb207: Totally unnecessary as long as you escape the input properly in your query. I would say that "redirect" should instead just output a 404 directly. It's ridiculously annoying from the user's side to have the server redirect if the page isn't found, you lose the previous address and have no way to see what might be wrong (plus, a 404 header is the correct one, not 302 redirect).

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. Basically, you have a page with links. Each link passes an id it got from a SELECT. My query function calls a confirm_query function. If it passes, it returns my set, if it fails, I redirect (via header) to an oops page. Since the links know the id, basically i know the id is there. I just thought best practices suggest you test that incoming id to make sure it's there. No? Sorry for the confusion on this. And yes, I accepted the answer. ;-)

Comment: @Madmartigan: Thanks for the tip. I really appreciate everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to check the incoming value and make sure it's a valid id from the database IS to query it against the database. Simple, eh?

> I want to protect against people inserting bogus values after the ? in the url.

The answer is even simpler - you can't.
You can validate your id though, but personally I seldom bother validating variables for such a silly reason.

Comment: Common sense to the rescue! Also, `0` may very well be a valid id - and if you're using slugs instead like `example.com/?slug=test-for-inserted-values-in-url` then there's no way to "validate" them without a db query.

Answer (score -1):

On the target page I would just check $_GET['id'] to make sure it's an integer in the range you need and if not, default it to some value or redirect the user.

```
if(is_int($_GET['id']) And $_GET['id']>=1 And $_GET['id'] <= 1000) {
    //proceed
}
else {
    header('Location:...'); // or set $id to a default value
}
```

Comment: My next step was to redirect too! Cheers!